# How to use correctly plotm after worldmap function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, maps, coordinates

I have set of dots with coordinates (lat and lon) I want to plot on a map. I have managed to use `worldmap` function for plotting the area I want. However, when I add after it `plotm`, I get the map without the dots. How can it be fixed? it is part of an animation, that's why the hold functions.

```
lat_rng=[20 40];
lon_rng=[-80 -30];
ax = worldmap(lat_rng,lon_rng);
setm(ax, 'Origin', [0 180 0])
land = shaperead('landareas', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow('landareas.shp', 'FaceColor', [0.5 0.7 0.5])
hold off
plotm(latitude_N,longitude_E,'LineStyle','none')

hold on

title('ABC')
xlabel('Longitude (E)')
ylabel('Latitude (N)')
hold off
drawnow
```

Comment: Ok, I have removed them, but still, the dots are not displayed

Comment: Thank, but dots still do not appear for some reason...